# Error local virtual host laravel

Tags: laravel, virtualhost

I have this error when creating my virtual host on windows with xampp:

when loading the address of the virtual host load the browser that I have wrong? I attach the configuration codes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkbGD.png)

[image]

file httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\front-micovinoc-transaccion\public"
    ServerName preferencial.dev
    ServerAlias preferencial.dev
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\front-micovinoc-transaccion\public">
         Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

file hosts windows

```
127.0.0.1       preferencial.dev
```

thanks.

Comment: I don't get it.What is the error? What happens when you hit `http://preferencial.dev` (with http://) in the browser?

Comment: @manix As you can see the image opens a browser instead of my web page

Comment: Looks like the browser is displaying a local content because of character wrong encoding. What error and access log say?